# Why does Oracle hang on "ALTER TABLE ADD ... NOT NULL"?

Tags: oracle, hang

Using Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0, the operations below have completely stumped me. The first locks up (table has DDL lock, finally killed query after 20+ minute wait). The second does not.

###This hangs:

```sql
ALTER TABLE customer ADD primary_seg varchar2(9) NOT NULL;
```

###This does not:

```sql
ALTER TABLE customer ADD primary_seg varchar2(9); 
ALTER TABLE customer MODIFY primary_seg NOT NULL;
```

There are no records in the table, there are no other users than myself on the instance, and I have no other queries executing which might cause a lock.  The table previously had a large number of rows that were removed via `TRUNCATE TABLE`.   There are no foreign keys or other referential constraints.

Comment: You say this is on 10.2.0.1? Have you tried this on a latest patchset (or any later) release?

Comment: Does this still happen if you drop and recreate the table?

Answer (score 0):

My case is similar, my talble has 3 million rows. It hangs about 2 hours and I abort it.

I found  the reason is some other sessions lock this table. After I killed the sessions, It completes adding column in miliseconds.

I don't know why Oracle don't throw "resource busy" when adding column.